# Table Visual as per Slicer Selection

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table visual that should have totals of employees count for each BRANCH( as per REGION selection in slicer), company total.

**Requirement**: If the region of North is selected in the slicer then the table visual should display the values for branches in the north region.

**Problem**: I am unable to get the branch wise values in the table visual as per the slicer.

I tried creating a measure for a branch and added it to the visual but when another region is selected, there is no data.

Please see screenshot below for more details:
[image]
[image]

Measures I have used:

```
Company Total = 
VAR _TotalAvg =
    CALCULATE (
        CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( EmployeeCount[EmployeeID]),
            ALL (Branch[Region] ),
            ALLSELECTED ( 'Date'[Year] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( EmployeeCount[weeknum]),
        _TotalAvg,
        SUMX ( VALUES ( EmployeeCount[weeknum]), _TotalAvg )
    )
```

This below one to show how the values should be showing the table visual for all branches in the selected region.

```
Manang = CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( EmployeeCount[EmployeeID]),
    FILTER ( branch, branch[Branch] = "Manang" )
)
```

Can anyone please let me know how I can achieve this?

Here is a reduced .pbix file on one drive. https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ave_-9o8DQVEgQ0MjEg21sSb38lT?e=pakuIP

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to dynamically change the measures shown in a Table visual based on a slicer selection.

Instead, consider using a Matrix visual, with a new measure based on `DISTINCTCOUNT ( EmployeeCount[EmployeeID])`, and then use BRANCH as a Column slicer in the visual.

Unfortunately, this technique would also repeat the [Company Total] measure for each branch, which is probably not what you want.

In general, though, for these "list"-type reports, consider using [Power BI Paginated Report Builder](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-paginated-report-builder-now-available/), which lets you control to a much finer degree how data is displayed in rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am not aware of the paginated report builder, I will take a look at that.

Comment: It's absolutely possible. I've done this in many reports using a `SWITCH`.

Comment: @AlexisOlson It's true that you can change the content of a single measure using SWITCH, but OP is asking to dynamically add or remove multiple measures from the visual based on the selection on a slicer, so that the total number of columns shown in the visual would change depending on the selection. DAX will not help you achieve that, since it's a matter of how the data is presented on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's still possible to do this with disconnected parameter tables, but rather hacky. Here's an example from one of my reports where the measures showing up are dynamically selected and the NAV measure only shows up once: https://i.imgur.com/bWCj9bC.png

Comment: Disconnected parameter tables are great, but you still won't be able to achieve exactly the same layout as OP is asking for. For example, the three left-most columns (weekname, startdate, dayofweek) would have to be added to the "Rows"-area of the matrix, but even though you can disable row subtotals and disable the "stepped" layout, Power BI won't repeat identical item labels: https://imgur.com/R0YYaxC - I may be nitpicking here, but sometimes you really need to create those pixel-perfect reports, and Power BI visuals are just not there yet...

Comment: Right. You'd probably make the date the unique item in the row and recreate `weeknum` and `DayOfTheWeek` as measures instead of row fields and ensure they don't get repeated for each branch.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this but it's technically possible.

If I had to, I'd approach it roughly as follows:

1. Create a calculated table, `slicer`, to use for your region slicer and branch column using something like `SUMMARIZE(branch, branch[Region], branch[branch])`.
2. Union that table with the cross-product of regions and measures. That is, regions `{NORTH, SOUTH}` and any measure names you want to use, `{weeknum, DayOfTheWeek, CompanyTotal}`.

```
CrossJoinTable =
CROSSJOIN (
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( { "North", "South" }, "Region", [Value] ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( { "weeknum", "DayOfTheWeek", "CompanyTotal" }, "Measure", [Value] )
)
```

3. Create a switching measure that reads in the `branch` column of your slicer table (which includes the measure names now too) and returns the appropriate measure. Something like this:

```
    Switching Measure = 
    VAR branch = SELECTEDVALUE(slicer[branch])
    RETURN
        SWITCH ( branch,
            "weeknum", [weeknum measure],
            "DayOfTheWeek", [DayOfTheWeek measure],
            "Company Total", [Company Total],
            CALCULATE(
                DISTINCTCOUNT ( EmployeeCount[EmployeeID] ),
                branch[Branch] = branch
            )
        )
```

In your matrix, put `StartDate` in the rows, `slicer[branch]` in the columns, and `[Switching Measure]` in the values.

---

As @Dan points out, there may be better tools for the job but sometimes a workaround is possible if you really need it.

Comment: Hey @alexis Could you please elaborate step 2 on your answer? I am unable to perform step 2.

Comment: I have also added one drive link to my .pbix file if required.

Comment: Can you please provide your input on step no. 2 ?

Comment: Hey @alexis, Thanks for the edit. I was able to get the steps done as you said but I did not get the company total measure on the matrix viz. I used the same code for switching measure you provided. Am i missing something?